# Why does the following string show a JSONException?

Tags: java, android, json

The following code generates a org.json.JSONException: No value for eqlocation.
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ doesn't show any error for the string.

```
String message="{"eqlocation": [{"lat": 38.3904, "lon": 73.8278}, {"lat": 19.0119, "lon": 95.5838}, {"lat": 12.9046, "lon": 92.2347}, {"lat": 34.1968, "lon": 80.7091}], "cydata": []}";

try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(message);
            Log.v("fromjson",jsonObj.get("eqlocation").toString());
        }
        catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No JSON received",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: Your json seems fine but the way you have initialized your string, it won't compile. You need to escape double quote character. What exact problem are you facing?

Comment: Can you post the logcat please

Answer (score 0):

The `json` looks fine but you're trying to parse an `Array` data.

Instead, you can try this:

```
try {

     JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(message);
     JSONArray jArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("eqlocation"); // get the array 

                for(int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++) { // loop through the items
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                Log.v("fromjson", json_data.getString("lat")); // get latitute here
              }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No JSON received",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Note: However, the way you initialized the `String` is not correct. You'll need to escape the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quotes inside the string and you can use a parser to simplify the proccess.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
String message = "{\"eqlocation\":[{\"lat\":38.3904,\"lon\":73.8278},{\"lat\":19.0119,\"lon\":95.5838},{\"lat\":12.9046,\"lon\":92.2347},{\"lat\":34.1968,\"lon\":80.7091}],\"cydata\":[]}";
try {
       Object obj = parser.parse(message);
       JSONObject obj2 = (JSONObject) obj;
       Log.v("fromjson",obj2.get("eqlocation").toString());
    }
    catch (ParseException pe){
        pe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You can see it working in plain java here: https://repl.it/repls/InvolvedSuperbSupport